# Data not showing in the UIcollection view. What did I do wrong

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, storyboard

My `UICollectionView` is not showing data, what did I do wrong?

Here is the collection view controller class:

```
class SongfeedViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionview: UICollectionView!
    
    var posts = [Post]()
    
    private var song = [songs]()
    private var songsCollection : CollectionReference!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        songsCollection = Firestore.firestore().collection("Songs")
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) 
    {
        songsCollection.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            if let err = error{
                print("Error Fetching Docs:\(err)")
            
            } else {
                guard let snap = snapshot else{return}
                for document in snap.documents{
                    let data = document.data()
                    let fullname = data["fullname"] as? String ?? "Anonymous"
                    let songname = data["songname"] as? String ?? "Anonymous"
                    let youtubelink = data["youtubelink"] as? String ?? "Anonymous"
                    let moneyoffer = data["moneyoffer"] as? String ?? "Anonymous"
                    let instalink = data["instalink"] as? String ?? "Anonymous"
                    
                    let newsong = songs(fullname: fullname, songname: songname, moneyoffer: moneyoffer, youtubelink: youtubelink, instalink: instalink)
                    
                    self.song.append(newsong)
                }

                self.collectionview.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.posts.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionview.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! postCell
        
        cell.artistnamelabel.text = self.posts[indexPath.row].fullname
        cell.moneyofferlabel.text = self.posts[indexPath.row].moneyoffer
        cell.instaUsernnamelabel.text = self.posts[indexPath.row].instalink
        cell.songnamelabel.text = self.posts[indexPath.row].songname
        cell.youtubelinklabel.text = self.posts[indexPath.row].youtubelink
        
        return cell
    }
```

The data from firestore is not showing on the UI collection view.

A code from my postcell is below:

```
import UIKit

class postCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var artistnamelabel: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var moneyofferlabel: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var songnamelabel: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var youtubelinklabel: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var instaUsernnamelabel: UITextField! 
}
```

Comment: This was mentioned in an answer but it's more of a typo than anything. Within the delegate function `collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection`, this code `return self.posts.count` will always return 0 because nothing is added to that array. e.g. self.posts is initialized `var posts = [Post]()` but never populated with data.

Answer (score 1):

Your `numberOfItemsInSection` and `cellForItemAt` functions are looking onto `posts` array

but in your closure You're inserting data into `song` variable

and `posts` still empty when collection is reloaded

Comment: tried changing everything to song variable. still not working. Do you think there might be a problem with my uploading to the firestore.

Comment: Did u added songsCollection.dataSource = self enywhere?

Comment: no i did not but i did add a ,swift file for the songs variable.